# ^M char creates extra new lines when using echo | mail

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I have a file that look like this:

```
> cat my.txt
This is sentence 1.
This is sentence 2.
<empty line>
This is sentence 3.
```

In my bash script, when I add try to email the file, an extra line appears.

```
#!/bin/bash
outf="/tmp/my.txt"
action=`cat $outf`
echo $action | mail -s "my test" emailid@mail.com
```

This is how the email looks like:

```
This is sentence 1.
<empty line>
This is sentence 2.
<empty line>
<empty line>
This is sentence 3.
<empty line>
```

How do I remove the extra empty lines?

Comment: As @ormios implies in their answer, the way your file looks may not match what's actually *in* the file.  There may be additional newline or carriage return characters.  Alternatively, the mail systems involved (is the mail sent elsewhere or delivered locally?) may interfere here.  Verify that no odd characters are included in your input file.

Comment: You are right.  There's "^M" char at end of each line.  Since the file is generated dynamically, how do I remove them with script?  Any idea.

Comment: Try @ormios 1st example: `tr -d '\015' < $outf | mail -s "my test" emailid@mail.com`

Comment: Please modify your question to take into account what you've learned so far.

Comment: Nice, no need extra script :).  Thanks for your help, Henk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unix, the character transliteration tool 'tr' exists

To remove CR=13(dec)=0D(hex)=15(oct):

```
tr -d '\015' < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

To remove LF=NL=10(dec)=12(oct)

```
tr -d '\012' < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

To remove both:

```
tr -d '\015\012' < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Not quite sure how this works in linux but: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tr.htm

Comment: Thanks the first example does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-n` option:

```
$ echo -n foo
```

This will supress the newline.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  -n doesnt work.  Found ^M at end of each line in the text file.  Need to find a way to remove them automatically via script.

Comment: Thanks again, i think this may help.